# what is the best practice of get value from a map?

Tags: c++, stl

i am a little confused with function return, my purpose is to avoid copying as much as possible.

i read some doc, which tolds me dont use reference as map's value.

but in the following code, i am puzzled.

```
struct BigCls {
  // this struct has a expensive constructor
  BigCls(...);
};

// solution 1
void create_function() {
  std::map<int, BigCls> m;
  m[1] = BigCls(...);
  m[2] = BigCls(...);
  ...
}

BigCls get(int a) {
  return m.at(a);
}

// solution 2
void create_function() {
  std::map<int, BigCls*> m;
  m[1] = new BigCls(...);
  m[2] = new BigCls(...);
  ...
}

BigCls* get(int a) {
  return m.at(a);
}

// solution 3
void create_function() {
  std::map<int, BigCls&> m;  // i think if map's value is reference, then the cls should be static
  // or it will fail, am i right?
  static BigCls cls(...);
  m[1] = cls;
  ...
}    
BigCls& get(int a) {
  return m.at(a);
}
```

which one is the fastest? and which one you think is the best one?

Comment: I don't understand the question? is that about speed or about references? BTW there is no link between having refereces and data being static

Comment: about speed, i think reference can avoid copy, so it can be fast, but i dont know which one is the fastest between pointer and reference, especially when it comes to map

Comment: looking up a value in a map by itself does not make a copy. It is not quite clear what problem you are trying to solve. Return a reference if you want a reference

Comment: seems premature optimization... your code does not even seem to work... and the problem statement not that clear. Avoiding copies; ok, but data need to live somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `std::map<Key,T,Compare,Allocator>::at`
>
> `T& at( const Key& key );` (1) (since C++11)
> `const T& at( const Key& key) const;` (2) (since C++11)
>
> Returns a reference to the mapped value of the element with key
> equivalent to key. If no such element exists, an exception of type
> `std::out_of_range` is thrown.
>
> ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at))

`std::map::at` returns an element reference, so there is no copy behavior (unless you assign its return value to a non-reference variable).

There is a problem with the code in the question, the `m` variable should not be inside the function.

Apart from this problem, changing the return type of the `get` function in solution 1 from `BigCls` to `BigCls &` would be the best solution.

```
struct BigCls {
  BigCls(...);

  int v1, v2;
};


std::map<int, BigCls> m;

void create_function() {
  m[1] = BigCls(...);
  m[2] = BigCls(...);
  ...
}

BigCls& get(int a) {
  return m.at(a);
}

void examples()
{
  int v1 = get(1).v1;

  BigCls &bigCls2 = get(2);
  int v2 = bigCls2.v2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to store references in the map to be able to get a reference to values in the map. Here:

```
std::map<int,BigCls> m;

BigCls& get(int a) {
  return m.at(a);
}
```

you are returning a reference to the value in the map. There are no copies made if you call it like this:

```
BigCls& x = get(42);
```

---

Storing pointers in the map is unnecessarily complicated unless you actually need that level of indirection (eg when `BigCls` is a polymorphic type).

---

> which one is the fastest? and which one you think is the best one?

This sounds like premature optimization. Choose to return a copy or a reference depending on whether you need a copy or a reference. It implies different semantics of the function. Worrying about performance is for when you have correct code and by profiling and measuring you found out that it needs to be improved.